# What would font-size:30; be equivalent to in px?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

`font-size:30;`

I know there's:
`em`, `px`, `pt`, and `percent`

What does it mean when there's only a number and nothing next to it?

Is there a name for that measurement?

Also, what would `font-size:30;` be equivalent to in `px`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be invalid. 
Here's a tip. Use your Developer Tools of your browser to test on your current website you are creating.

e.g: Google Chrome:
Go to Settings tab > More Tools > Developers Tool or Ctrl+Shift+I
The developer tools will help you as a guide to your workaround. 
The DevTools provide web developers deep access into the internals of the browser and their web application.

Answer (score 0):

These is none. Unitless `font-size` declaration is invalid and will be ignored by a browser:

```html
<div style="font-size: 14;">14</div>
<div style="font-size: 20;">20</div>
<div style="font-size: 26;">26</div>

<div style="font-size: 14px;">14px</div>
<div style="font-size: 20px;">20px</div>
<div style="font-size: 26px;">26px</div>
```

If you look at this element in developer tools, you will see that it is ignored as invalid:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only write font-size:30; It will not affect to your website

Answer (score 0):

```
Do you need like this,

<div style="font-size: 10;">10</div>
<div style="font-size: 20;">20</div>
<div style="font-size: 30;">30</div>

<div style="font-size: 10px;">10px</div>
<div style="font-size: 20px;">20px</div>
<div style="font-size: 30px;">30px</div>
```

you can see the variations in the link:https://jsfiddle.net/17d80ym3/18/

Answer (score 0):

CSS supports a number of measurements including absolute units such as inches, centimeters, points,pixels and so on, as well as relative measures such as percentages and em units. You need these values while specifying various measurements in your Style rules e.g border = "1px. Sometimes it depends on your browser. What's the browser's default configuration for unit measures for css. But I think in Google-Chrome pixel is the default unit that's specified for css and beyond versions. 
So, yes `font-size:30;` would be equivalent to `30px` in `px`.